# Sending URLs to server from Chrome Extension background.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a simple Chrome Extension to get the URL of each of the users browser pages when opened and send back to the server. 
I can currently get the URL to appear in an alert box, however my ajax is returning a blank value to my database. The alerts work fine though(?)

Any ideas/thoughts? See script below..

Popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Facebook Connect For Chrome Extension</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Facebook Connect For Chrome Extension</h1>
        <p><a target="_blank"href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY-APP-   ID&response_type=token&scope=email&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com">Facebook Connect</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

*UPDATED* background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo != undefined) {
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  http.open("POST",
  "http://ec2-52-89-93-50.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/phpindex.php", 
   true);
  sendme = changeInfo.url
   http.send(sendme);
}
alert(sendme);
});
```

*UPDATED* manifest.json:

{
    "name": "Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Example"

```
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_icon":"icon.png"
 },

"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"manifest_version":2,
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"http://*.facebook.com/*",
"http://MY_SERVER/*",
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*",
"<all_urls>"
]
}
```

Comment: You `manifest.json` doesn't include `background.js`. and `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` is enough. you don't need others.

Comment: I had just left it out when posting on here, I've amended the code above. still doesn't seem to be working. Just get a blank inputs  in MySQL database

Comment: I strongly suggest removing `chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener` and `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener`. it's not necessary. So, with above code, you can receive callback when tab's url is updated?

Comment: I've deleted the other code in background.js, leaving chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener. When i test I get 3 alerts, the first has the correct URL, the second and third just have 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

As per [tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) documentation:

> Note that the tab's URL may not be set at the time this event fired, but you can listen to onUpdated events to be notified when a URL is set.

Use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener callback to post the url to your server.

Comment: Thanks - bizarre I've updated my background.js yet still isn't picking it up?

Comment: 1. Make sure to reload the extension 2. Use the debugger

Comment: Thanks, this hasn't really helped. I have used debugger and of course reloaded the extension. Potentially could this be due to restrictions for background pages? E.g versus using a content page?

Comment: Well, you've switched to `tabs.onCreated` which has the same problem as `tabs.onActivated` (see the documentation), however both the documentation and the answer were advising `tabs.onUpdated`.

Comment: I've changed my background.js file.. But still receiving blank inputs in the database.. Could it be a restriction on background scripts?

Comment: Do you see the correct url in `alert(changeInfo.url);`?

Comment: I've deleted the other code in background.js, leaving chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener. When i test I get 3 alerts, the first has the correct URL, the second and third just have 'undefined'.

Comment: Then you should check if the url is defined and only post it to your server in that case.

Comment: I've updated code to check for undefined, this sends to the server and is still showing a blank input

Comment: Maybe there's something's wrong with the database configuration? Check by running `var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); http.open("POST", "http://MY-SERVER.php", true); http.send("test");` from the console of the background page.

Comment: Console is returning <-undefined and my server is showing blank inputs again?

Comment: Which means there's a problem with XHR. Usually the data is sent to php in the form of `param=value` ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15312976/3959875)).

Comment: Updated the code, still not sending. This is very unusual :/

Comment: The unusual thing in your code is the lack of the standard `param=value` notation in `send` and no `Content-type` and/or `Content-length` headers as shown in the example.

Comment: `sendme = changeInfo.url` is not the same as `send("param=" + encodeURIComponent(changeInfo.url))` where of course `param` should be the real param name from your php code.